# Apply button need to be disabled but unable to disable onclick of Toggler2 button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While loading, the Apply button needs to be disabled and on click of Toggler1 button, I want to change state ie one of the tabs flag will be true, so apply button should enable, once the flag is true in any of the tab and when the flag is false in any of the tab, Apply button should be disabled,when we click on Toggler2 button,am setting the state with flag condition flase,am unable to disable the Apply button.
am checking the condition for flag, based on this am seting the state ie setEdit(flase), since its in loop, am unable to set state properly

onclick on Toggeler1 button, Apply button will be enabled and on click of toggler2, Apply button need to be disabled but unable to disable the Apply button eventhough flag is false in data
https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-platform-l5m8g?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let items = [
    {
      tab: "tab1",
      info: [
        { mnemonic: "first", flag: false },
        { mnemonic: "second", flag: false }
      ]
    },
    {
      tab: "tab2",
      info: [
        { mnemonic: "first", flag: false },
        { mnemonic: "second", flag: false }
      ]
    },
    {
      tab: "tab3",
      info: [
        { mnemonic: "first", flag: false },
        { mnemonic: "second", flag: false }
      ]
    }
  ];
  let item2 = [
    {
      tab: "tab1",
      info: [
        { mnemonic: "first", flag: true },
        { mnemonic: "second", flag: false }
      ]
    },
    {
      tab: "tab2",
      info: [
        { mnemonic: "first", flag: false },
        { mnemonic: "second", flag: false }
      ]
    },
    {
      tab: "tab3",
      info: [
        { mnemonic: "first", flag: false },
        { mnemonic: "second", flag: false }
      ]
    }
  ];
  const [edit, setEdit] = React.useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(items);

  const changeFlag = () => {
    setData(item2);
  };
  const changeFlag1 = () => {
    setData(items);
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    data.forEach((_eachItem) => {
      const isChanged = _eachItem.info.find((_each) => _each.flag);
      if (isChanged) {
        setEdit(false);
      }
    });
  }, [data]);
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={changeFlag}> Toggler1</button>
      <button onClick={changeFlag1}> Toggler2</button>
      <button disabled={edit}> Apply</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `array::forEach` is a void return and you don't really do anything in the forEach loop (*you call `find` on an array, but don't do anything with the result*), so `isChanged` will always be falsey. `setEdit` isn't in a loop. Your question and issue are totally unclear.

Comment: updated the description and code,onclick on Toggeler1 button, Apply button will be enabled and on click of toggler2, Apply button need to be disabled

Comment: "once the flag is true in any of the tab and when the flag is false in any of the tab, Apply button should be disabled"...so the Apply button should be disabled *always* since a flag will always be either true or false? It still isn't clear at all what you want this code to do. What is `isChanged`?

Comment: once the flag is true in any of the tabs, i need to Enable the Apply button and when the flag is false, i need to disable the Apply button,isChanged will track flag,onclick of Toggler1,one of the flag will be changed(state change already taken care) and onclick of toggler2 all the flag will be false(state change already taken care), so button should be disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for ***some*** item in `data` array to have ***some*** element in the `info` array to have a truthy `flag` value. This can be done with [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
const isChanged = data.some((item) => item.info.some((el) => el.flag));
```

Your effect needs to check if this condition is met and update the `edit` state with the opposite to disable the Apply button.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const isChanged = data.some((item) => item.info.some((el) => el.flag));
  setEdit(!isChanged);
}, [data]);
```

[image: Edit apply-button-need-to-be-disabled-but-unable-to-disable-onclick-of-toggler2-butto]

Alternatively you use Array.prototype.every and check that ***all*** data items have all falsey info flags and return and set the positive affirmation for the edit/disabled mode.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const isChanged = data.every((item) => item.info.every(({ flag }) => !flag));
  setEdit(isChanged);
}, [data]);
```

Comment: item.info.every(({ flag }) => !flag)) ->can you explain here, are we checking the flag condition or we assigning the flag value

Comment: @chidananda Checking and returning the flag condition. `Array.prototype.every()` takes a callback that returns a boolean value, and the `flag` property is conveniently a boolean value. The only assignment in either snippet is to `isChanged`. If the syntax looks a little funny it is object destructuring. `({ flag }) => !flag` is the same as `(el) => !el.flag`.

Comment: why are we using !condition here, what makes difference, why is it required, since every() will return boolean value

Comment: @chidananda Because *some* is equivalent to *!every*. Your condition is that if *any* flag is true then Apply "disable" is false. `array::every` means that every condition ***must*** be true in order for the overall check to be true. The condition is that all flags are false. If any flag is true then the condition fails and false is returned, i.e. `edit` is false and the Apply button is not disabled.